# javascript alert not rendering (invisible) in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I run this in Firfox 3.6.13 and click either the link or the button, the alert appears but is basically invisible. It shows the outline of a box and the content of the alert only appears after I hover over it.

What is causing this? It works as expected in IE 7.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['link'])){
?>
    <script>alert('link!');location.href='test.php';</script>
<?php 
}
if (isset($_GET['button'])){
?>
    <script>alert('button!');location.href='test.php';</script>
<?php
}
else {
    print "<a href=\"test.php?link\">click me</a><br/>";
    print "<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"location.href='test.php?button'\" value=\"button\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: Post the generated code. The above code is not running in the browser.

Comment: `$HTTP_POST_VAR` and `$HTTP_GET_VAR` are deprecated. Use `$_POST` and `$_GET` instead (and I would not use `extract` at all).

Comment: changing to $_GET and removing extract makes no difference. I edited the source above with your suggested changes.

Comment: I tried this exact same code on FF 3.6.13 and it worked just fine. Is there some other code that you're not posting that may be causing this?

Comment: no other code. that's it. I'm running this on xampp. here's all of the info on firefox: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 AskTbFXTV5/3.9.1.14019 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729.

Comment: Gentoo Linux / Firefox 3.6.13, experiencing same behavior... most interesting. @ferrari: my first try I got normal behavior too - but reloading and trying again leads to the weirdly drawing alert. Could this be a firefox bug? o_O

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same behaviour with your code, but if I put the alerts in a function that gets called when the body is loaded (i.e. : body onload="load();") everything is fine.